# How To Extract Data Attributes in HTML using Rails Nokogiri gem?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I want to extract the data from the HTML.
I only need to extract the value of the data attributes
not the content of the whole div or the text

example:

```
<div class="c-rating-stars  c-product-card__rating-stars " data-value="3.333333">
```

I only need to extract the **3.333333** value

here's my code

```
require 'rails'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("www.url.com"))

page.css('[data-value]').each do |item|
   puts item
end
```

However my code extract all of the content inside the div

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Try this one:**

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("[insert URL here]"))
dataVvalue = doc.css('div.c-rating-stars')[0]["data-value"]
```

Comment: that would work if one data need to extract however there are hundreds of them
<div class="c-rating-stars  c-product-card__rating-stars " data-value="3.333333">
<div class="c-rating-stars  c-product-card__rating-stars " data-value="2.67777">
<div class="c-rating-stars  c-product-card__rating-stars " data-value="5.0000">

and soon

Comment: Please explain why this answer might work over what has been tested and @RuelNopal please use backtick's (left of the 1 key) to put a code block in comments.

Comment: @Martin, how do you discover what keyboard layout another user has?  Sounds like it might be a useful feature, but I never realised you could do that!

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm pretty sure most keyboard layouts the backtick is in the same place and especially if they have the number 1 key...

Comment: the page has multiple div with the different value for data-value
```
<div class="c-rating-stars  c-product-card__rating-stars " data-value="3.872093"></div>
    <div class="c-rating-stars  c-product-card__rating-stars " data-value="4.50000"></div>
```

and some of the  div has no value at all as the data is base on the rating of the products

so 
`dataVvalue = doc.css('div.c-rating-stars')[0]["data-value"] `
might work if you want to get one data value but for multiple data it does not work.